# How do I select a portion of a source video clip that I can then drop onto sequencer?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

One of my source clips is 30 minutes long, but I only need 10 seconds of it. How do I select just those 10 seconds and drop them onto the sequencer?

Have not found answer anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Import the whole 30 mn and cut off the part you want with <kbd>K</kbd>.

Keep in mind that the video files that are used by the *Video Sequencer* are not part of the blend file so even if the source video is 30 mn it won't make the file heavier.

What you can do instead is extract the 10 sec you need in a video software and only import this sample. This way you can get rid of the 30 mn video if you don't want to keep it in your hard drive.